# android textview clickable words

Tags: android, textview

So I have this **Activity B** with **textview**. The string to be displayed into textview comes from my previous **Activity A** (a result query which contains more than one record/Passed thru Bundle )

My question is how do you make each record clickable? Note that in my Activity B, I only have one textview for the string from **Activity A**. I want each word to be clickable and then it will go to its corresponding activity.

**FYI,**
This is the selected

[image]

**UPDATED:**

**Result.class**

```
     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.symptomsresult);

    result = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvSymptomResult);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
       if (extras != null) {
            String value = extras.getString("results");
            result.setText(value);
            }
            else{

            }

}
```

**Symptoms.class**

```
   String[] symptoms = alSymptoms.toArray(new String[alSymptoms.size()]);

        String c = dbHelper.getData(symptoms);

        final int result = 1;
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SymptomsResult.class);
        extras.putString("results", c);
        i.putExtras(extras);
        startActivityForResult(i, result);
```

**DBHelper.class**

```
     public String getData(String[] symptoms) {
    String where = KEY_SYMPTOMS + "= ?";
    String orStr = " OR "; /* Maybe " AND "? */

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(where);
    for(int i = 1; i < symptoms.length; i++)
        builder.append(orStr).append(where);

    String search = "";
    Cursor c = myDataBase.query(true, DB_TABLE, new String[] 
            {KEY_CONDITIONS}, builder.toString(), symptoms, null, null, null, null);

    c.moveToFirst();

    while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
        search += c.getString(0) + ", ";
        c.moveToNext();
    }

    return search;

}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: use a listview instead of textview. Each row of listview can contain the words. On click open corresponding activity.

Comment: @Raghunandan yup I consider using listview, please have a look on my updated post where I included my codes.

Comment: So how do I put them in a listview? I think you answered one of my questions, this one should be the follow up.

Comment: store all results in a arraylist of string (in youractivity A) and provide listview adapter with the arraylist data.

Comment: If you want to do some styling with listview row items use a custom listview.

Comment: @Raghunandan Can you give me an example how to do that? Thanks

Comment: Using a ListView how @Raghunandan says is a nice idea, then you can make ActivityB extends from a ListActivity. Look at this example
http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php
 BestRegards!

Comment: yup you can do that. Custom listview is recommendable.

Comment: @vgarzom I just want to display it in the standard listview

Comment: What do you mean with standard listview? This example is much more simple: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the [Linkify](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) class and [Spannables](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html). But I believe a [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) is a better choice, the items are easier to click because they are bigger and this approach has much more documentation.

You can still use the code I wrote in `getData()` but rather than turn the Cursor into a String, pass your Cursor to a SimpleCursorAdapter.

---

> So how do I put them in a listview?

Modify `getData()` like so:

```
public Cursor getData(String[] symptoms) {
    String where = KEY_SYMPTOMS + "= ?";
    String orStr = " OR "; /* Maybe " AND "? */

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(where);
    for(int i = 1; i < symptoms.length; i++)
        builder.append(orStr).append(where);

    return myDataBase.query(true, DB_TABLE, new String[] 
            {"rowid as _id", KEY_CONDITIONS}, builder.toString(), symptoms, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Then pass this Cursor to a CursorAdapter and bind it to a ListView:

```
String[] fromColumns = {DBAdapter.KEY_CONDITIONS};
int[] toViews = {android.R.id.text1}; // The TextView in simple_list_item_1

setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getData(symptoms),
        fromColumns, toViews, 0));
```

(I made a few assumptions here, but this is how to bind a Cursor to a ListActivity.)

Comment: If I understood you well, the latter code should be placed in my Activity A or B?

Comment: This should be Activity B.

Comment: One thing, symptoms variable is not declared in my Activity B. So how can I pass the symptoms from Activity A to B?

Comment: Good point. You can pass `symptoms` to the second Activity in your Intent. Use [`putExtras()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29) like so: `intent.putExtras("symptoms key", symptoms);`.

Comment: Like this: Cursor c = dbHelper.getData(symptoms);

            final int result = 1;
      Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            Intent i = new Intent(this, SymptomsResult.class);
            extras.putStringArray("results", symptoms);
   i.putExtras(extras);
   startActivityForResult(i, result);

Comment: And retrieve it using: Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
       String[] value = extras.getStringArray("results");
       
        String[] fromColumns = {DBHelper.KEY_CONDITIONS};
        int[] toViews = {android.R.id.text1}; // The TextView in simple_list_item_1

        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dbHelper.getData(value),
                fromColumns, toViews, 0);
        
    lv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled( true );
        
        }
      else{
       
      }

Comment: Looks great, how does it perform?

Comment: It has nullpointerexception in this line:                 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dbHelper.getData(value),

Comment: Did you initialize `dbHelper` in `onCreate()` with something like `dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);`?

Comment: Of course I did initialize it. Still getting nullpointerexception :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25386/discussion-between-sam-and-betty-barnes)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HTML href` as the value of your text and then add this line to make it appear as web link

```
txtView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

You can open your activity on click by making the link with a custom `scheme`

Example code:

```
txtView.setText(Html.fromHtml(String.format("<a href='%s://%s'>%s</a>", 
                                                           schema,action,text)));
```

And for the activity that you want to open when this link is clicked you have to add the following in the `manifest`

```
<intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data
       android:host = "YOUR_ACTION"
       anroid:scheme="YOUR_SCHEME" />
</intent-filter>
```

The trick here that you are creating your custom URL and instead of the `host` you have an action that can be set to launch different activities. Note that `action/host` and `scheme` can be any arbitrary string as long as they match with the values you use when creating the link

So when you click that text with such link it will invoke the activity that matches `scheme/host`

I am using this solution in very similar case to yours and it is working perfectly.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not gonna link to a web page.

Comment: No problem, I use the same to link to an `activity` just you need the activity to listen to specific `scheme`

Comment: I added more details to my answer to show you how you can implement a complete solution i.e. open a certain activity when a link in TextView is clicked.